# Setting flash data for a query result array and accessing/displaying all data in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a users comment that they have posted into the thread to be displayed when they click the submit button on the create comment form. But the comment doesn't show up without refreshing the page (which also duplicates the comment). This is why I am trying to achieve this using redirect which I am finding difficult.

Currently in my controller i have the following code..

```
...

$query = 'SELECT * FROM thread where id='.$id;
$data['thread'] = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

$query2 = 'SELECT username FROM newUsers where id='.$userid;
$data ['username'] = $this->db->query($query2)->result_array();

$query3 = 'SELECT id FROM newUsers where id='.$userid;
$data ['userid'] = $this->db->query($query3)->result_array();

$query4 = 'SELECT * FROM comments where thread_id='.$id;
$data['comment'] = $this->db->query($query4)->result_array();
```

I displayed this data in my view and all works fine with the following method....

```
$this->load->view('header', $data);
$this->load->view('discussion/create');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

The problem I faced was the comment not appearing when the page loaded.. I know i have to use the following

```
redirect('postComment/post','refresh');
```

In my controller/method, i have the following method

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('discussion/create');
$this->load->view('footer2');
```

Im currently trying to pass this data with flash data which i'm not sure if its the best way.. i'm using the following code for this..

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('thread', $data['thread']);
$this->session->set_flashdata('username', $data['username']);
$this->session->set_flashdata('userid', $data['userid']);
$this->session->set_flashdata('comment', $data['comment']);
```

In the view I am trying to set the data the following way..

```
$data['thread'] = $this->session->flashdata('thread');
$data['comment'] = $this->session->flashdata('comment');
$data['username'] = $this->session->flashdata('username');
$data['userid'] = $this->session->flashdata('userid');
```

To display the data i am using the following..

```
foreach($thread as $t):

$t['id'];
$t['thread_title'];
$t['subject'];
$t['content'];
$t['created'];
$t['votes'];

endforeach;
```

I get multiple undefined variables and Invalid argument supplied for foreach().. Any help for my problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Flashdata is only for temporary things and will only work on page refresh. just use set_userdata. Let me know if that resolves your issues.

Comment: That being said I really don't understand why you are storing all this in a session and not just getting it on the fly?

Comment: I was using flash data as i would only need it temporally and its a lot of data to keep.. I've just tried set_userdata and changed each for each loop to $data['thread'], $data['comment'] etc.. And this has solved my problem. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flashdata is only for temporary things and will only work on page refresh *once*. You could use `set_userdata()` and just set the variables as a regular session variable, then when you are done with them you can unset them.

However I think it would be prudent to look into why you are doing this with session variables rather than getting the database rows on-the-fly. As you database tables get larger this will eventually be problematic.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term 'on-the-fly'.. what do you mean/ do you have a simple example?

Comment: Like: $this->db->query($query4)->result_array();